# grails GORM: how to access id of super class

Tags: grails, orm, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

I inherited a Grails 1.3.9 project that I need to maintain.

There is a situation when one of the controllers needs to be extended to log creations of extended appointments.

The appointments are defined like this:

```
class Appointment implements Serializable{

    static mapping = {
        table 'appointment'
        version false
        tablePerHierarchy false
        id generator:'sequence', params:[sequence:'seq_te_id']
        cache true
        columns{
            id column:'te_id'
            start column: 'te_start'
            // Other columns follow
        }
     }
  }
```

Special appointment:

```
class SpecialAppointment extends Appointment implements Serializable {

  static mapping = {
      table 'special_appointment'
      cache true
      columns{
          id column: 'pt_id'
          comment column: 'pt_name'
          // other columns
      }
   }
}
```

History log:

```
class AppointmentHistory {
    static mapping = {
        version false
        table 'appointment_history'
        id generator: 'sequence', params:[sequence:'seq_th_id']
        cache true
        columns {
            id column: 'th_id'
            termin column: 'pt_id'
            // other columns
        }
    }
}
```

In the controller to create SpecialAppointment, which has Appointment as its base class, I need to create and save new instance of AppointmentHistory, which has a relation to Appointment.

```
def app = new SpecialAppointment()
// set fields here

app.save(flush:true)

// save history log
def history = new AppointmentHistory(appointment: app)
```

I passed instance of SpecialAppointment when creating history object, but it is wrong, because it uses its ID, instead of ID of Appointment.

Unfortunately I was not able to figure out **proper syntax** to access members of super class from just saved instance of derived class.

Please advise.

Comment: It sounds to me like this should be a composition rather than an extension - SpecialAppointment should _not_ be a subclass of Appointment, but rather should be a separate class that holds a (probably non-nullable) reference to an Appointment.

Comment: Yes, it might be better to implement it that way, however this is a part of a larger application and I'd rather not change these relations.

What is the proper syntax to explicitly access members of the super class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real problem was that the relations between domain classes were not properly set.

`AppointmentHistory` needed `belongsTo Appointment` and `Appointment` needed `hasMany AppointmentHistory`. The history item must be added to appointment with `app.addHistoryItem(history)`.

These changes solved the problem.

Thanks everybody for support.

Answer (score 0):

SpecialAppointment being a sublcass of Appointment produces only one object and one row in the table, so they have common ID. Inheritance is not a relation where one sub-object contains the super-object, but a sub-object IS as super-object as well

in other words, it's fine that it uses ID of SpecialAppointment, because SpecialAppointment can also be referenced by Appointment class object

Comment: I think SpecialAppointment should have a reference to an Appointment. Just like it's said in the answer, you don't have and Apointment and a SpecialAppointment, just the second one. If you want to access a related Appointment from a SpecialAppointment, you must have both items stored and refereced

Comment: Appointment does not have it's own ID, they have one common ID, because they are one object (not two)

Comment: @KamilMikolajczyk Each of the domain classes is mapped to its own table. When creating new SpecialAppointment, a related entry to Appointment is created as well. And both have id columns. (http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#inheritanceInGORM)

Comment: oh, ok, I didn't see the "tablePerHierarchy" mapping, but still, I'd expect them to have the same ID in both tables

Comment: @KamilMikolajczyk They don't have the same IDs, because SpecialAppointment is not the only class inherited from Appointment.

Comment: you are saying this because you actually see it in your db or just guess? I created a project for testing and it behaves like I expected and wrote earlier - despite that every subclass has its own table, the objects still have the same ids. I created one Sub object, it had id=1 in both tables, then one Base object it had id=2, next Sub object had id=3 in both tables (there was no id=2 in Sub table). Moreover, from OOP point of view, as I wrote earlier subclass object IS also a superclass object, they share super class properties, so calling explicitly super class properties make no sense

Comment: if they really had different ids, how would these two records be related? is there any additional FK column in SpecialAppointment class? if so, then as Ian Roberts said, there should be composition in domain classes and not inheritence